# Issue with a php prepared statement throwing a null error

Tags: php, sql, insert

The issue I am having appears to be an error with the way i'm creating my prepared sql statement to insert some data. My first thought was that something was null, but I know the data is there because i've tested it with an echo. My thought is it has to be with the way the statement is written but I can't figure out what could be wrong with it.

Code:

```
// Set up the sql command
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tblcomments (imgpath, author, comment) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
    // Bind the data
    $stmt->bind_param("imgpath", $imagePath);
    $stmt->bind_param("author", $author);
    $stmt->bind_param("comment", $comment);
    // Execute the sql
    $stmt->execute();
    // Close the statement
    $stmt->close();
```

The issue is the insert statement itself, at least according to the error, which is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in D:\Inetpub\vhosts\kreativecoating.com\httpdocs\commentDataPostHandler.php:55 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Inetpub\vhosts\kreativecoating.com\httpdocs\commentDataPostHandler.php on line 55
```

Line 55 being the one with the insert statement. So my question is am I doing something wrong with the prepared statement? I've checked the database fields for typing errors so it isn't that. There is an id field not listed in the sql but thats the key and auto increments, so it shouldn't need to be there

Comment: Hint: Your database connection failed and/or `$mysqli` isn't initialized.

Comment: What "data" is there? The error is pretty clear that, for whatever reason, `$mysqli` is `null`.

Comment: The database connection appears to be working fine and there doesn't seem to be an issue with initialization that I can see>

As for what data, its three pieces of data being fed in via an app using json. Its been retrieved, decoded and assigned variables, and appears to output fine using echo, it just seems to have some kind of issue with the sql, which is what is driving me nuts

Comment: This is just a guess, but I bet this is a variable scope issue. Like you initialized `$mysqli` outside of the function, and you expect to use that variable without declaring it `global`. But what is actually happening is that PHP is trying to reference a *local* variable `$mysqli` which doesn't exist.

Comment: bind_param($types, $variables); is the correct syntax. Answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind param is all at once.

```
bind_param("ssi", $string, $string, $number);
```

S for string

i for integer

d for float / decimal number

I made a query Builder that actually generates all the code. Just plugin in column names. It helps with prepared queries :)

https://wbr.bz/QueryPro

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have been the issue. Its working now

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark it as answer if it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

If Your db connection is working, maybe try this on your bindParam() statement. Since you are using question marks  your insert values, then it should go like this:

$stmt->bindParam( 1, $image);

$stmt->bindParam( 2, $author);

$stmt->bindParam( 3, $comment);

$stmt->execute();